# http file upload handler fails silently in case of too large files (although there is check to limit response size)

Tags: go, http, file-upload, webserver

Noob question: when creating web server with various functionalities for study project, I ran into problem with file uploading to server:
The handler function should check for file size, and return re-rendered upload webpage with additional error message.
If the file size is slightly larger than the limit, it works fine.
However, if file is much larger, it fails silently.

```
request.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, request.Body, 20 << 20)

if err := request.ParseMultipartForm(20 << 20); err != nil {
        dataStruct.Errors = append(dataStruct.Errors, "image_too_large")
        template.Execute(writer, dataStruct)
        return
    }
```

Code runs until return, there is no errors indicating that template parsing failed any way, but in browser the page is not returned, with status (failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I used as a guidance several different tutorials that suggested similar approach - for instance, https://tutorialedge.net/golang/go-file-upload-tutorial/

Expectation:
template executes and returns the initial upload page with additional message (implemented in html template, triggered by "image_too_large" error in dataStruct.Errors)

What happened:
When test file size was relatively small compared to limit, but still over limit (22Mb vs 20Mb) everything worked as should.
When file was considerably bigger, (30Mb vs 20Mb) error described upwards happened.

Additional testing:
I also checked if the the template rendering was the problem (seems that not)
When I switched `template.Execute(writer, dataStruct)`  with `http.Redirect(writer, request, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)` the same thing happened - with slightly larger file redirected to root page, with considerably larger - error.

Update:To answer to clarification requets:
error from parsing the multipart form is "http: request body too large" - which is as intended. Theoretically I could have just pushed the error string to the array, and read that one in the html template if condition..., dunno is there any difference in providing string from error, compared to just giving your own string ?

error from template.Execute() was nil

Comment: What is the `err` you are seeing? You append it to some data structure but don't seem to inspect it.

Answer (score 2):

The connection reset error is expected.

When the server application's request limit is breached, the server stops reading the request body. The server closes the network connection after the application's request handler returns.

The server's network stack responds to data sent to the closed connection with a connection reset. After receiving the connection reset, the client's network stack returns a connection reset error on writes to the network connection. Because of buffering in the client's network stack, the request must be a good bit larger than the server's read limit for this condition to trigger.

If the http client writes the entire request to the network connection before reading any of the response (as most do) and the http client gives up after experiencing the connection reset (as most do), then the server's response is not read by the client.  The client application only sees the connection reset error.

---

The call to request.ParseMultipartForm returns a non-nil error when the request limit is breached.  You are not observing this error because the client ignores the response written by the server.

To get some visibility into this, add code to log the error returned from request.ParseMultipartForm and template.Execute.

Comment: Updated my initial problem description.

Comment: @Moridio  The problem is unrelated to the string used for the response.  If the client's request is significantly larger that then server application's read limit, then the client receives and reports a connection reset instead of reading the server application's response.

Comment: Ok... so - as I understand, this is how it is supposed to work ? In this case would there be some kind of way to adjust the response message, to provide well-formed page with error information ?